# Mac won't boot after changing date

Tags: macos, startup

A few days ago I changed my M1 Mac Mini system date to may of 2122. That sounds stupid and it was. I did it as a joke to see how fast somebody would notice.

I could not open anything on the web because web page certificates don't reach that far. I tried to change it back, but no matter how many times I tried it just jumped right back to 2122. I decided to restart my computer.

It started to boot as usual, but then bright pink splashed on the screen and it started to reboot. It was cycling this process until I turned it off with the push of a button.

I left it unplugged for a night and tried to repair it the next day.

I read that you need to hold the power button for a few seconds, get the boot menu, click options, and then reinstall macOS. I was ready to do that, I got to the boot menu, but I can't click anything there. When I try to click continue or even shut down nothing happens. I can move the cursor, but clicking doesn't work at all. Trying to do it with my wireless (not Bluetooth) keyboard didn't help either.

Can anybody help me? I'm running macOS 13 Ventura, don't know which version exactly.

Any help would be appreciated, but please don't shame me about changing the date. I started to tinker with it to test my app and the idea about changing it absurdly far came later.

Comment: Boot into recovery and change date in terminal.

Comment: Sadly I can't do that. I have M1 mac, which means that for booting into recovery I need to turn it on holding power button, then click options, then recovery mode, but clicking just doesn't work for me. If I can get into options, I'm pretty sure I'll manage to resolve the problem. There is shortcut for booting in to recovery, but it only works for Intel macs.

Comment: This is an excellent test! I would also call Apple Support (or use the support app from a phone or pad or web) - they might have a trick that's not documented here or that we've seen. Also, they will perhaps add it to the things they should test in the future when they release new OS or new recovery tools. This is how we learn things, good luck on your recovery here. It's also possible there's something other than the date change at play here.

Comment: Thanks! I think of calling them tomorrow. I'm 100% sure that problem is date change, cause before that my mac was working flawlesly for the past year. Hope they will fix it in the future

Comment: I doubt they know it fails, it likely isn't in the test case. (Now most people have it to auto set time).

Answer (score 2):

I would perform a "revive" operation on this since there is no NVRAM to reset on Apple Silicon Macs.

- https://support.apple.com/guide/apple-configurator-mac/revive-or-restore-a-mac-with-apple-silicon-apdd5f3c75ad/mac

  ### What does a revive do to your Mac?

  A revive updates the firmware and updates recoveryOS to the latest version. A revive is designed to not make any changes to the startup volume, the user’s data volume, or any other volumes. User data may be retained if recoverable.

---

If you don't have all the cables and tools needed, you could try a boot to *Paired recoveryOS* which is a [normal part of the Apple Silicon boot process](https://support.apple.com/guide/security/boot-process-secac71d5623/web)

> From a shutdown state, [**press and hold** the power button](https://support.apple.com/guide/security/boot-modes-sec10869885b/web).

Answer (score 0):

while rebooting, are you connected via wire or wireless to the internet?

Try without ... To be sure, to have no connection switch off your router so that the computer can't check in with another one to know the time is wrong.

Comment: I use wireless. I'll try switching off router. Interesting idea. Thanks!